# A/C not turning on when it should

Tags: hvac

Our A/C is set at 74 it is 75 in here and for 20 minutes I waited for it to kick on. It never did. I turned down to 73 and it kicked right on. Last year A/C guys said there was a delay set so they fixed it. Heater sometimes didn't kick on until 2 degrees off too but not always. I've checked everything I know how. Already had maintenance done this year and they said everything was fine so don't want to pay another service call if I don't have too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you familiar with the normal tolerances of thermostats (a couple degrees +/- by design)? Also are you familiar with "short cycling"?  which means it damages an A/C to turn on too soon after it is shut off, so once it goes off, a safety feature will make it wait awhile before restarting.

Comment: One degree difference might not be enough for it to turn on or off.  Imagine if you have it set for 74, when it is on it will go slightly below 73 before turning off and will not turn on again till it hits 75.2 or 75.3(or a bit more).

Comment: If you are too hot, turn it down. If you are too cold, turn it up. Pay less attention to the numbers...

Comment: Most 'set' temperature on a thermostat should be consider as the average temperature(+/- two degrees), not the constant temperature it will keep the room/house at.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  How I deal with it: sometimes I put on an extra layer and then take it off while I'm waiting for it to kick on again.  Sometimes I supplement the AC with a fan.

Answer (score 3):

Thermostats that control heating and air conditioning will have a "dead band".

The "dead band" is usually set at 2-4 degrees F. Electronic thermostats can be adjusted and if set to *"cool only"*, the  temperature differential can be reduced.  But if this is taken too low, it will cost more. Most people cannot tell the difference in 2 degrees F, but at 4 degrees we can. So using *"cool only"*, adjusting the dead band or “span” works well.

Where lowering the dead band is not a good idea, is when in *"auto"*... as the system will switch from cooling to heat then back. But this is why there is a delay between absolute values.

If this is important, the values can be adjusted to +-0.  So the cooling will go on ***at*** set point, but this will raise your power bill, and should only be done in cooling OR heat mode... with the off cycle set to ~3 minutes for most systems to prevent short cycling.

Comment: This sounds intriguing but I'm having trouble following the ideas -- could you edit and add some more punctuation so an idiot like me will be able to follow?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like perfectly normal behavior for a thermostat. Normally, a thermostat will have a dead spot of 2 to 4 degrees (F) and won't keep the temperature *precisely* at the number you've got it set for.

If you're cooling to 74°F, the thermostat won't call for air conditioning until the temp reaches about 76°F, then it will run the AC until the temp is down to about 72°F and turn it off. It will then wait until it's back up to 76° before turning the AC on again. Likewise, if you're heating to 68°F, it will let the room cool to 66°F before heating it to 70°F, then allow it to cool again.

This is done for multiple reasons.

1. It's almost impossible to keep a room's temp at precisely one temperature. Air moves, people enter and leave, the temperature will fluctuate with all those and more. Turn on the TV and some incandescent light? Temp goes up. Close the blinds, temp goes down. You don't want the heat or AC turning on and off with every little movement in your house.
2. Turning an AC unit on/off very frequently is called short-cycling, and it's very bad for the unit. At a minimum, it can cause the coils to ice up which causes your AC to quit working until they defrost.
3. I'm sure there are more that I'm not aware of and people will probably chime in with comments.

If your HVAC guys "fixed" it last year, they may have reduced the dead band from 4° down to 2° to make it more responsive and reduce the temp swings, but, realistically, that's about all they *can* do. You really don't want them doing any more than that because you won't like the results.

If you're cooling, and it's getting too warm for you, turn the temp down a degree. It will cool a little colder before allowing the temp to climb again. Keep the peak temp to a point where you're comfortable and if that means that you're a bit chilly when the AC kicks off, keep a light sweater handy to throw on for 10 or 15 minutes until it warms up just a touch. Anything else just won't work well and will shorten the life of your HVAC system.